# Android studio 3.1.2 create new project gradle sync failed

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I use this Android studio import existing project all the time and everything goes well. Today ,I first create new project which support c++ ,and after every step to the final, I got the error.Picture like below:
[image: after create steps]

I don't know what's wrong,because when I importing existing project ,this error haven't shown.
And the project structure panel like below:
[image: only have "SDK Location" and "Project" item]

When I check connection in "Http Proxy" ,it returns successful :
[image: http proxy settings]

[image: I test connect stackoverflow.com successful]

Comment: It says there’s an error in opening zip file. Can you add your gradle file as well?

Comment: @Khanal It's generated automatically by the IDE,I haven't fixed a letter.

Comment: i have the nearest error at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51591429/android-studio-3-1-3-create-new-project-with-c-support-sync-failed, Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

**Delete** the **corrupt files**
When Gradle files are not completely downloaded or corrupted by some other reason,we have to redownload the files. The easy way is to delete the old files in.

**C:\Users\username.gradle\wrapper\dists**
Then rebuild the project.
Then Android Studio will automatically download the new files from the system.

Comment: Thank you so much! I found that there are two folders under the dists path,they all contains gradle file of version 4.4.But one contains incomplete files.So I deleted it.Now the project shows sync in progress...But I cannot understand why I already have a gradle 4.4 in the dists path , the new project still will download a new one?

Comment: Now it's ok! The problem totally because my network isn't good at the moment,the gradle file haven't download completely.I delete the incomplete folder and download gradle again, the problem has gone.

Comment: Good news :) (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout)
please upvote and mark it as an answer if it helped you.

Thank You