# Android studio 3.1.3 create new project with c++ support sync failed

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

I am using Android studio 3.1.1 to create a new project with c++ support, but i could not do anything and it sync failed,the message is below:

```html
Build command failed.

Error while executing process E:\AndroidSDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HF:\ASworkspace\TestJniApplication\app\src\main\cpp -BF:\ASworkspace\TestJniApplication\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-19 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=F:\ASworkspace\TestJniApplication\app\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DANDROID_NDK=E:\AndroidSDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=E:\AndroidSDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=E:\AndroidSDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja}

-- Check for working C compiler: E:/AndroidSDK/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe

-- Check for working C compiler: E:/AndroidSDK/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe -- broken

/AndroidSDK/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe"   is not able to compile a simple test program. 
Open File

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: F:/ASworkspace/TestJniApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

  Run Build

  Command:"E:\AndroidSDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe"

  "cmTC_bc909"

  [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_bc909.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

  [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_bc909

  FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd .  &&

  E:\AndroidSDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe

  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi

  --gcc-toolchain=E:/AndroidSDK/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64

  --sysroot=E:/AndroidSDK/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot

  -isystem

  E:/AndroidSDK/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi

  -D__ANDROID_API__=19 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables

  -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-pre-- Configuring incomplete,fixes -march=armv7-a
 errors occurred!

  -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat
```

[image]

and the sdk is good and newest,

[image]

then the gradle vers ion is 3.1.3.i have no idea about this,could anyone help me?
Thank you.

Comment: 1) Post error messages as text, not as images. 2) Post the full error message, not just the initial part.

Comment: There's no error in that error message. You omitted the important part.

Comment: hello,i am sorroy about that and there is the error message uploaded,Please

Comment: Just share a JNI example project https://github.com/russell-shizhen/JniExample in case you want to try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702` is too old for Android Studio. Not sure why your project is still using this old tool chains.

Just delete this ADT bundle (it was release in 2014 and really too old to be compatible with your Android Studio 3.1.3). Just download the latest Android Studio and use the built-in SDK and NDK bundle will work well.

You can double check your **ndk** and **sdk** settings from your `local.properties` under your project root and it should be something like below

```
ndk.dir=<your-ndk-root-dir>
sdk.dir=<your-sdk-root-dir>
```

Comment: thank you very much,adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702 is just a path where i store the sdk,and i have resolved this error by changing my sdk path,"E:\AndroidSDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk" is the previous path,then i change it to "E:\AndroidSDK\sdk",it works good for me.